# Проблема с проверкой файлов

Tags: java, android

Пишу приложение, в котором можно установить все игры компании.

Проблема с проверкой файлов. Если я захожу на страницу игры первый раз, пишет что игра в обновлении не нуждается, хотя это не так. Стоит выйти на список всех игр и когда возвращаюсь - уже подгружает нормально данные.

Пробовал многое. И загружал заранее и цикл выносил. Ничего не помогло. Меня эта проверка ввела в ступор.

Код:

```
if(!App.getInstance().isGameFilesValid(this, id)) { // сама проверка
            statusLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            statusText.setText("Доступно обновление игры.\nДля установки обновления нажмите на кнопку справа.");
            Utils.setInstallType(Utils.INSTALL_TYPE_UPDATE_GAME_FILES);
            Utils.setInstallingGameID(id);
            downloaderResumeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            playBtn.setClickable(true);
            playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.reg_btn_end);
            statusLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            statusText.setText("Установлена актуальная версия игры: " + verName);
        }

public boolean isGameFilesValid(Context context, int gameID) {
    loadGameFilesList(context, gameID);
    for(int i = 0; i < gamesFiles.size(); i++) {
        File file = new File(Config.getGamePath(gameID)+gamesFiles.get(i).path);
        if(!file.exists() || !Utils.checkMD5(context, gamesFiles.get(i).size, file)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

ну а loadGameFilesList просто загрузка данных с json (retrofit2), она работает идеально.

Comment: Загрузка же наверняка асинхронная, а вы сразу после её старта уже обращаетесь к результату. Вам нужно после загрузки всех файлов дёрнуть метод, который проверит загруженное и отобразит результат в UI

Comment: @woesss, я уже пробовал вызывать его заранее. вообще не помогло.

Comment: Я не говорил про заранее. Я говорил про обратный вызов после загрузки.